# Installing slime and emacs

Tags: fedora, emacs, debugging

I'm trying to install SLIME on Fedora 17 so that I can do some lisp.
Here is what I downloaded:
http://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/#downloading

The CVS Snapshot link.

I have a .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/programming/slime/slime-2012-09-18")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/sbcl")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

When I start `emacs --debug-init`, I get the following message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "slime")
  require(slime)
  eval-buffer(# nil "/home/sam/.emacs.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 159
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sam/.emacs.el" "/home/sam/.emacs.el" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the .emacs code you've posted, so the problem must be that there is no readable slime.el or slime.elc file in `~/programming/slime/slime-2012-09-18`.

Comment: Ok, am I downloading the right files ? The link of what I downloaded is in the first message.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is a few years back...This worked for me just moments ago in Fedora 21, changing line 2 to:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```